# unknown element in a template

Tags: angular, angular-material, navigationbar

I am developping an angular application. I try to implement a navigation toolbar with material design. I try to reproduce this example on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I have a component, AppListProduitImmobilierComponent:

```
import ......
import {VERSION} from '@angular/material';
import {NavItem} from './../nav-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-list-produit-immobilier',
  templateUrl: './app-list-produit-immobilier.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-list-produit-immobilier.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppListProduitImmobilierComponent implements OnInit {
  ......
  ......
  public version = VERSION;
  public navItems: NavItem[] = [
    {
      displayName: 'DevFestFL',
      iconName: 'close',
      children: [
        {
          displayName: 'Speakers',
          iconName: 'group',
          children: [
.....
.....
```

With its template :

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="menu-bar mat-elevation-z1">
  <div style="width:100%;" class="md-toolbar-tools" >
    Liste des annonces
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
  <span *ngFor="let item of navItems">
    <!-- Handle branch node buttons here -->
    <span *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu"
        [disabled]="item.disabled">
          {{item.displayName}}
      </button>
      <app-menu-item #menu [items]="item.children"></app-menu-item>
    </span>
    <!-- Leaf node buttons here -->
    <span *ngIf="!item.children || item.children.length === 0">
      <button mat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="item.route">
          {{item.displayName}}
      </button>
    </span>
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div fxLayout="row">
.........
.........
```

My editor mention an error on the following element in the template:

```
<app-menu-item #menu [items]="item.children"></app-menu-item>
```

The error is :

```
 'app-menu-item' is not a known element: 1. If 'app-menu-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

However MenuItemComponent is declared in the root module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .......
    MenuItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    .......
  ],
  providers: [.....],
  bootstrap: [......],
  entryComponents: [.........]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the component MenuItemComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NavItem} from '../nav-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-item',
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-item.component.scss']
})
export class MenuItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() items: NavItem[];
  @ViewChild('childMenu', {static: false}) public childMenu;

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

With its template:

```
<mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <span *ngFor="let child of items">
    <!-- Handle branch node menu items -->
    <span *ngIf="child.children && child.children.length > 0">
      <button mat-menu-item color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu">
        <mat-icon>{{child.iconName}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{child.displayName}}</span>
      </button>
      <app-menu-item #menu [items]="child.children"></app-menu-item>
    </span>
    <!-- Handle leaf node menu items -->
    <span *ngIf="!child.children || child.children.length === 0">
      <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="child.route">
        <mat-icon>{{child.iconName}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{child.displayName}}</span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

I spent time trying to resolve it, but I don't see the solution. Could you help me ?

Comment: Your editor says that there is an error. But Does your code compile correctly without error ? And where have you defined AppListProduitImmobilierComponent ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wandrille and Rafi Henig were right. I turned off my computer yesterday night and turned it on this morning and the error has gone. To answer your question, wandrille, the AppListProduitImmobilierComponent is defined in the routing module.

Furthermore, I had to change this line:

@ViewChild('childMenu', {static: true}) public childMenu: any;

. The discussion is CLOSED. Thanks again for your answers

Answer (score -1):

'app-menu-item' is the component selector and the error is telling you that the selector isn't recognized. This in turn means that the selector's component (MenuItemComponent) isn't recognized. You have to register MenuItemComponent in the appropriate module for your application (e.g. in app.module or else in another feature module perhaps). Here's the official guide for syntax: [ngmodules](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)

The component needs to be in the declaration section of one module.

Comment: Looking at his code,  MenuItemComponent is included in the appropriate module

Comment: Given that ‘restarting the computer’ “fixed” the problem it suggests to me that temporarily the component wasn’t declared. If you make multiple changes in angular during development  it’s possible that some won’t be picked up due to timing. That’s why restarting appears to solve. Stopping and starting ng serve also will do the trick.